# Multiple socket i/o using node

Tags: node.js

Here is a summary of my application requirement. The app needs to process a batch of 10000 items and then upload the processed data on multiple servers using socket i/o. After the upload is done, move to the next set of 1000. I know in java this would mean creating multiple threads and start uploading simultaneously. Since nodejs is single threaded, i'm not sure how can i achieve the same effect of making simultaneous connection  and uploading in parallel. Can anyone give me some pointers or sample sudo code for guidance.

Comment: No idea about node.js, but out of curiosity, why not java? With java you can also use [NIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) which will make it much more efficient.

Comment: This is my weekend projet. I've learned some theory on nodejs and did some small sample applications. Now i want to try writing something new.

Answer (score 0):

Check out threads_a_gogo : https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo

It lets you create -up to thousands of- JavaScript threads to run JS code in parallel with node's main thread, using all the available cpu cores, in v8 isolates, from within a single node process.

I know this is very experimental, but since this is a simple project you're working on, it should fit the bill.